# Highcharts - How to implement good real-time live chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts to plot data in real time.
However, when the refresh interval is less than 1 sec, the animations end up causing rendering problems:

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/maf23rja/
Test2: http://jsfiddle.net/maf23rja/3/

I want to implement a fluid animation, something like:
http://jsfiddle.net/maf23rja/5/

The best I could do was to disable the animations, and create (repeated) data in 80ms to generate the real-time effect.

> http://jsfiddle.net/maf23rja/4/

```
events: {
    load: function () {

        var lastValue = 0;

        // simulate data from websocket
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function () {
            lastValue = Math.random();
        }, 500);

        // Simulate realtime animation
        setInterval(function () {
            //var x = new Date().getTime();
            var x = lastIndex++;
            series.addPoint([x, lastValue], true, true, false);
        }, 80);
    }
}
```

But I think this can lead to performance and memory consumption problems.

Comment: Both examples work perfectly on my machine.   Maybe you don't have quite enough processor horsepower?

Comment: The example you provide of the fluid animation uses a `SmoothieChart()`.  Why don't you try that?

Comment: I already have a large code base implemented with highchart. In the examples you did not realize that the points already plotted have strange animations?

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean now. Have you asked Highchart about this yet?

Comment: Your last example seems to work fine.  What's the problem?

Comment: With multiple graphics on the same page, I think this can lead to a memory consumption problem.

Comment: Don't guess.  If there is a memory consumption problem, prove it by running a profiler, using Performance Monitor or some similar technique.

Comment: If you want to animate the chart on your own then you should disable animation in Highcharts. I do not see how your solution might cause memory/perf issues.

Comment: I think this is a problem in highcharts, I do not think it's reasonable to resvoler the way I solved it